# xml.etree.ElementTree - problem with .remove() functionality

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have a problem with xml.etree.ElementTree remove() function. I am parsing data from string to my program, and want to remove the elements which match the pattern from given list(self.given_list in my code below), but when I start the program, it shows error:

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Even if I print it above and I can see that is exists.
Code is shown below:

```
     target_view_config = ET.fromstring(source_view_config)
     for source_item in target_view_config.findall('jobNames/string'):
             for target_item in self.given_list:
                 if((source_item.text) == target_item):
                     target_view_config.remove(source_item)
                     break
```

Comment: you need to call `remove` from the direct parent of `source_item`. My guess is that your matches are within a different subtree of the top ElementTree

Comment: @JoshSharkey you are right, matches are nested in XML, in these structure:
root->jobNames->string. Then how to remove string?

Comment: Ok I solved it on my own, by calling an object with object = target_view_config.find('jobNames') and then did object.remove(source_item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it on my own, by calling an object with

```
object = target_view_config.find('jobNames')
object.remove(source_item)
```